Setting XFCE4 terminal font programatically
I am installing fonts on target PCs using Ansible. This step went OK, but I am unsure how to set installed font as the default for various terminals. For example, I tried editing :
${HOME}/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-terminal.xml

by adding
<property name="font-use-system" type="bool" value="false"/>
<property name="font-name" type="string" value="JetBrains Mono NL Light 12"/>

after all other properties. However, If I set font manually via terminal's preferences, run Ansible and start terminal again - it shows old, manual configuration.
Mainly, I am interested in XFCE4 terminal and iTerm.
